# Tweepy Why did I receive AttributeError for search

Tags: python, tweepy

I received the following error message when I ran the code. The code should return the tweets that match the specified query. Did Twitter block the search attribute?

Error Message

```
for tweets in api.search(q="iphone", lang="en"):
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search'
```

Code:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = "XX"
consumer_secret = "XX"
access_token = "XX"
access_token_secret = "X"

# Creating the authentication object
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
# Setting your access token and secret
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
# Creating the API object while passing in auth information
# Creating the API object while passing in auth information
# Creating the API object while passing in auth information


api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweets in api.search(q="iphone", lang="en"):
    print(tweet.text)
```

Comment: Try 1) `pip uninstall tweepy` 2) `pip install git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git`

Comment: Perhaps you meant a different method like .search_tweets()?

Answer (score 13):

Yes! `search` is not a valid attribute. According to the docs, you should use
`search_tweets`.

Docs are [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=search#search-tweets).

```py
for tweets in api.search_tweets(q="iphone", lang="en"):
    print(tweet.text)
```

Answer (score 4):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) was released yesterday and renamed `API.search` to [`API.search_tweets`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.0/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets).

I would recommend simply renaming your method call, but you could also downgrade to Tweepy v3.10.0.